# How can I make tow way binding in vue js dynamic variable and get value after press submit

Tags: javascript, vue.js, typescript-typings

I have Vuejs App read data from the local file and then create Form depending on these data, so my problem is when I press to submit a form the data doesn't print on a console, I don't know why but I guess the problem related with the name of the field because it's binding dynamically.

example.yaml

```yaml
Metadata:
  Form:
    fields:
        - 
            type: email
            lable: Email
            name: email
            placeholder: Enter Your Email

        -    
            type: text
            name: username
            lable: Username
            placeholder: Enter Your Username

        -
            type: number    
            name: age
            lable: Ege
            placeholder: Enter Your Age

    dropdowns:
        -
            name: gender
            lable: Gender
            placeholder: Select a City
            options: 
                - name: Male
                - name: Female
                - name: Other
```

page.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="about">
    <div class="container">
      <Panel header="Dynamic Form" style="margin-top:100px">
          <form @submit.prevent="save()">
              <span class="p-float-label" style="margin-bottom:5px" v-show="metadata.fields.length" v-for="(field, i) in metadata.fields" :key="i">
                <InputText id="username" 
                  style="width:70%"
                  :type="field.type"
                  :name="field.name" 
                  :v-model="field.name" 
                  :placeholder="field.placeholder"/>
                <label v-html="field.lable"></label>
              </span>

            <span class="p-float-label" v-for="(dropdown, j) in metadata.dropdowns" :key="'a'+j">
              <Dropdown v-show="metadata.dropdowns.length"  
                style="width:70%"
                :name="dropdown.name"
                :v-model="dropdown.name" 
                :options="dropdown.options" 
                optionLabel="name" 
                :placeholder="dropdown.placeholder" />
                <label v-html="dropdown.lable"></label>
            </span>
          <Button style="width:70%; margin-top:10px" label="save" type="submit" class="p-button-success" />
        </form>
      </Panel>
    </div>    

  </div>
</template>
```

```js
created(){
    var yamlContent = jsyaml.load(txt);
      this.metadata = yamlContent.Metadata.Form;

      Object.keys(this.metadata).map((element)=>{
        let fields = this.metadata[element];
        fields.forEach(field => {
          Object.defineProperty(this.$data, field.name, this.attributes);

        });
      });

  },
 data(){
    return {
      metadata: {},
      attributes:{
        value : ``,
        writable : true,
        enumerable : true,
        configurable : true
      },
      formdata:{}
    }
  },
  methods:{
    save(){
      console.log("Data was saved", this.$data, this.gender);
    }
  }
```

so when the app run this `console.log("Data was saved", this.$data, this.gender);`
instead of actual value of `gender` I get `undefiend`

Could someone help me please.

after update console print:

```
attributes: Object
configurable: true
enumerable: true
value: ""
writable: true

formdata: Object
age: ""
age2: ""
email: ""
email2: ""
gender: ""
username: ""
username2: ""

metadata: Object
dropdowns: Array(1)
0:
lable: "Gender"
name: "gender"
options: Array(3)
0:
name: "Male"
1:
name: "Female"
2:
name: "Other"
placeholder: "Select a City"

fields: Array(3)
0:
lable: "Email"
name: "email"
placeholder: "Enter Your Email"
type: "email"
1:
lable: "Username"
name: "username"
placeholder: "Enter Your Username"
type: "text"
2:
lable: "Ege"
name: "age"
placeholder: "Enter Your Age"
type: "number"
``
```

Comment: what does console.log(this.$data) print?

Comment: @LHJ thanks to a reply, I update the question to print console

Comment: It looks like you're dynamically adding data props in `created()`, but that should be done in `data()`. Just modify the returned object in `data()` to include those fields rather than attaching them to `$data`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
Vue.component('v-select', VueSelect.VueSelect)
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      formdata: {},
      metadata: {
        fields: [
          {
            type: 'email',
            lable: 'Email',
            name: 'email',
            placeholder: 'Enter Your Email',
          },
          {
            type: 'text',
            name: 'username',
            lable: 'Username',
            placeholder: 'Enter Your Username',
          },
          {
            type: 'number',
            name: 'age',
            lable: 'Ege',
            placeholder: 'Enter Your Age',
          }
        ],
        dropdowns: [
          {
            name: 'gender',
            lable: 'Gender',
            placeholder: 'Select Gender',
            options: [
              { name: 'Male' },
              { name: 'Female' },
              { name: 'Other' },
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  created() {
    // your yaml import
    Object.keys(this.metadata).map((element)=>{
      let fields = this.metadata[element];
      fields.forEach(field => {
        this.$set(this.formdata, field.name, '')
      });
    });
  },
  methods: {
    save() {
      console.log(this.formdata);
    },
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-select@latest"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/vue-select@latest/dist/vue-select.css">
<div id="app">
  <form @submit.prevent="save()">
    <div 
      v-show="metadata.fields.length" 
      v-for="(field, i) in metadata.fields" 
      :key="'f' + i">
      <input
        :type="field.type"
        :name="field.name" 
        v-model="formdata[field.name]" 
        :placeholder="field.placeholder"/>
      <span>{{field.name}}</span>
    </div>

    <div 
      v-show="metadata.dropdowns.length"
      v-for="(dropdown, j) in metadata.dropdowns" 
      :key="'d' + j">
      <div>{{dropdown.name}}</div>
      <div>
        <v-select 
          style="width: 200px;"
          v-model="formdata[dropdown.name]" 
          :options="dropdown.options.map(o => o.name)"
          :placeholder="dropdown.placeholder" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <button 
      type="submit"
    >
      submit
    </button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Is this what you r trying to achieve?
I don't have your button, dropdown and inputtext component, so i use html input, button and v-select component to replace dropdown

There is some problems in your code.

1. v-model not :v-model
2. to use vue data variable, use {{ variable_name }}, not v-html
3. i am not sure if it is correct to write Object.defineProperty(), but i never use it in vue before. However, you can use this.$set/Vue.$set to add new property to data. https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-set
4. to assign v-model to dynamic variable(dynamic field.name in your case), what i would do is declare an empty object, and assign dynamic property to the object. In this case, v-model="formdata[field.name]" not v-model="field.name".

Comment: perfect bro, it's working fine
thank you for your tips and recommendation, I'll put it in my consideration